# Navegador móvil en aplicaciones Híbridas - Ionic

Tags: javascript, html5, ionic, cordova, phonegap

Utilizo el framework `Ionic` para desarrollador aplicaciones híbridas. La duda que me surge es... En el caso de Android, ¿Que navegador utiliza mi móvil para abrir las aplicaciones desarrolladas? ¿Android Browser? ¿Chrome for Android?.

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que utiliza la API de Speech Recognition de `HTML5` y solo tiene soporte para Chrome, Opera y Chrome for Android. ¿Existe la posibilidad de que el `.apk` generado tras el build utilice un navegador específico?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si no me equivoco, y según he visto en la página de *Ionic*, se utiliza el navegador por defecto del dispositivo, lo que en la mayoria de casos será el browser propio de *Android* o *IOS*. Sin embargo, sí que se puede cambiar, por lo menos para que utilice *Chromium*, que es una versión para desarrolladores de *Chrome*, en la que probablemente funcione tu *API*. Para ello necesitas un plugin llamado **Crosswalk**. Te dejo los enlaces del plugin y de *Ionic* donde comentan lo que te he dicho e incluso te dicen cómo incluir *Crosswalk*.

Crosswalk: https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

Información: http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/browsers.html

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, lo acabo de probar. Si que es verdad que con ese plugin genera un `.apk` de mayor tamaño y la aplicación se abre desde otro navegador. Para el caso de la API que comento, me sigue sin funcionar, luego me temo que este browser tampoco tiene soporte para Speech Recognition. En cualquier caso muchas gracias y buena respuesta!